# Ireland and Scotland Car Hire

Tags: uk, legal, car-rentals, ferries, ireland

My family and I are travelling from Australia in about a month.  We would like to hire a car from Dublin airport, drive north to Belfast, take it over to Scotland ( via ferry - no other way) and then back to Dublin airport over a period of a month.

Are there any car hire companies that will allow us to take the car from Ireland to the UK? (My research suggests not). Are there any additional steps that I have to take beyond normal renting of a car?

Comment: I will make a recommendation: do not rent a car in Ireland.  It seems to be a sketchy business to the point that credit cards that usually insure rental cars have special exemptions for Ireland.

Comment: @Louis IIRC lots of US credit card insurance excludes Ireland not because the hire car places are sketchy (they're fine), but because large numbers of their American customers can't safely drive on the tiny roads in Ireland and consequently have large numbers of expensive claims...

Comment: From a quick google, the [Hertz UK site says that there's a fee for taking a UK car to Ireland or Continental Europe](https://www.hertz.co.uk/rentacar/reservation/reviewmodifycancel/templates/rentalTerms.jsp?KEYWORD=DRIVINGRESTRICTIONS&EOAG=LHRT50). I'd assume it's much the same for a Hertz Ireland rental taking the car to the UK - possible but for an extra fee

Comment: Why would you want to pay both the extra rental fee, *plus* the cost of taking the car on a ferry? Passenger-only fares for ferries are much cheaper and you can simply rent a different car on the other side.

Comment: @Gagravarr Not only tiny roads, but muscle memory is to turn the wrong way.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus If it was just that, they'd exclude the UK too!